# Merge sensor data for clustering/neural net usage

Tags: matlab, sensors

I have several datasets i.e. matrices that have a 2 columns, one with a matlab date number and a second one with a double value. Here an example set of one of them

```
>> S20_EavesN0x2DEAir(1:20,:)
ans =

   1.0e+05 *

   7.345016409722222   0.000189375000000
   7.345016618055555   0.000181875000000
   7.345016833333333   0.000177500000000
   7.345017041666667   0.000172500000000
   7.345017256944445   0.000168750000000
   7.345017465277778   0.000166875000000
   7.345017680555555   0.000164375000000
   7.345017888888889   0.000162500000000
   7.345018104166667   0.000161250000000
   7.345018312500001   0.000160625000000
   7.345018527777778   0.000158750000000
   7.345018736111110   0.000160000000000
   7.345018951388888   0.000159375000000
   7.345019159722222   0.000159375000000
   7.345019375000000   0.000160625000000
   7.345019583333333   0.000161875000000
   7.345019798611111   0.000162500000000
   7.345020006944444   0.000161875000000
   7.345020222222222   0.000160625000000
   7.345020430555556   0.000160000000000
```

Now that I have those different sensor values, I need to get them together into a matrix, so that I could perform clustering, neural net and so on, the only problem is, that the sensor data was taken with slightly different timings or timestamps and there is nothing I can do about that from a data collection point of view.
My first thought was interpolation to make one sensor data set fit another one, but that seems like a messy approach and I was thinking maybe I am missing something, a toolbox or function that would enable me to do this quicker without me fiddling around. To even complicate things more, the number of sensors grew over time, therefore I am looking at different start dates as well.

Someone a good idea on how to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give an answer for the clustering part, because I have no idea what you're looking for in the data.

For the neural network, beside interpolating there are at least two other methods that come to mind:

- training separate networks for each matrix
- feeding them all together to the same network, with a flag specifying which matrix the data is coming from, i.e. something like: input (timestamp, flag_m1, flag_m2, ..., flag_mN) => target (value) where the flag_m* columns are mutually exclusive boolean values - i.e. flag_mK is 1 iff the line comes from matrix K, 0 otherwise.

These are the only things I can safely say with the amount of information you provided.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Edit: What I am trying to achieve is to have all the sensors' data in one matrix with a common timestamp, and that sounds to me like using interpolation. I am not using neural nets yet, but I intend to and prior to that I would like to have my data in a proper form that I would be able to use not just with neural nets, but with any kind of form of function that needs this kind of sorting i.e. either pre row or column the data and each column or row as sample

Comment: I don't think there's a way to have matlab automatically interpolate the data when feeding it to the network, let alone cope with the fact that the temporal ranges of the datasets are not constant (i.e. extrapolation). The two methods I outlined above are the ones I'd use if I were to tackle such a problem. For example, once you create the network as I described above, you could use it to do interpolation and extrapolation and obtain synchronous samples for all the datasets.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas on Neural nets and the approach. I have used another solution and interpolate the data according to the largest number of samples I have available. This will of course affect data that might be magnitudes smaller in sample size e.g. 229 vs 154616 and just blow it up, but that is at least for me the easiest way of making data consistent for NNs as well as other functions I want to use e.g. clustering and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first thought about interpolation was the correct one, at least if you plan to use NNs. Another option would be to use approaches which are designed to deal with missing data, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster%E2%80%93Shafer_theory for example.